# how to count percentage of 1 in the [1, 0] series in graphite

Tags: graphite

I have a series with [1, 0] value, how to count percentage of 1 in the whole series in graphite, I want to get the only one number of the percentage value like 99.19%

this [1, 0] series is like below:

```
isNonNull(local.random.diceroll)
```

Solved:

`averageSeries(isNonNull(local.random.diceroll))`

Comment: Can you not sum it and divide by its size?

Comment: yeah, I do not know how to get the size in graphite, but I noticed that `The percentage of values that are 1 in a series of 1 and 0 will be the average value of the series`, so I can just use `averageSeries(isNonNull(local.random.diceroll))` to solve this problem, Thanks

Comment: Good job solving your problem, but instead of adding your solution as an edit to your question, you should write a complete answer and accept it